# Unable to edit, bot's own message in Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    @client.command()
async def inspire(context):
    wait_msg = await context.send("Finding a quote for ya...")
    await wait_msg.edit(content=inspire())



Error : RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  await wait_msg.edit(content=inspire())
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

This method works on @client.event , but im getting a runtime error on @client.command, im new to bot development, so can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Comment: `content=inspire()` needs to change to your actual content you want to set

Comment: Joshua Nixon, the `inspire()` function returns a string, will that not work.

Comment: It doesnt return a string. inspire is your command function. Make sure functions have unique names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def inspire(context):
    wait_msg = await context.send("Finding a quote for ya...")
    await wait_msg.edit(content="this is the edit")
```

when you call for the edit you have to change the actual properties of the message which means if you want to change the content you need to give him a new content to change to. the reason for the error is that you were recursing yourself in an infinite loop so that was the runtime error.